# Improving performance in NodeJs API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, express, optimization

I've built an API using NodeJS and express and all has been working fine, but recently I've noticed a bit of a performance/bottleneck beginning to happen build due to the increase in calls and so the server can sometimes grind to a halt due to memory/cpu usage.

Scenario:

1. Every hour I have a cronjob firing to my api endpoint.
2. DB call (MongoDB) to get all items (approximately 800-900)
3. I loop through all items and call a 3rd party api with the details or my own DB and return results.
4. I then match the results to previous results stored in my DB
5. If the conditional statement is matched then it will send out an email and update the DB

I've tried to add a timeout to the loop so each call has a few seconds between them, the problem with this is for the site to scale to thousands of items, by the time the last one has run the cronjob would fire again.

I'm looking for any advice on how I can optimise the above scenario and prevent future bottlenecks and maximising the memory/cpu usage on the server.

Comment: You mentioned 5 things you are doing in your application. We can't judge if this can be simplified or optimized because we can't know if it's really necessary or if you could find a way which doesn't make these steps necessary. Also you haven't provided any code for the mentioned steps so we can't recommend you code optimizations which would lead to performance improvements. I recommend you to post your relevant code for each bullet (maybe even split it up into multiple questions). For the whole application itself you may want to create a question which describes your use case.

Comment: You could use `process.nextTick` or `setImmediate` to loop trough a large set of objects and not block the event loop. Let's say you only loop trough 50 objects / (possible) tick it would take longer to respond to the request but it wouldn't block the event loop. Additionally you could cluster your node server to use all available cpu cores on the machine. This has a downside since these will be all separate processes so each of these processes have there own memory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are currently doing processes on individual items, and will need to process in batches or perhaps trigger updates based on external changes rather than processing every item every hour.